# Android bitmap image is not saving to MySQL using PHP API

Tags: php, android, mysql, android-volley

I want to save a image to MySQL database with some other String values. But all my String values are saved but can not save the image. I am converting the Bitmap image to String and passing it to PHP script. In my PHP function I am trying to convert it to blob. This code does not give any error. But image is not saving where other values are saving.

Here are my attempts below.

My Java code:

```
private void registerUser() {
    final String email = editTextEmail.getText().toString().trim();
    final String password = editTextPassword.getText().toString().trim();
    final String userName = editTextUserName.getText().toString().trim();

    progressDialog.setMessage("Registering User...");
    progressDialog.show();


    //converting image to base64 string
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    userImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
    byte[] imageBytes = baos.toByteArray();
    final String imageString = Base64.encodeToString(imageBytes, Base64.DEFAULT);


    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, Constants.URL_REGISTER,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                    try {
                        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), jsonObject.getString("message"),
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                    catch (JSONException ex) {
                        ex.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    progressDialog.hide();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }){
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
            params.put("username", userName);
            params.put("password", password);
            params.put("email", email);
            params.put("userImage", imageString);
            return params;
        }
    };

    RequestHandler.getInstance(this).addToRequestQueue(stringRequest);

}
```

My PHP function:

```
public function createUser($username, $pass, $email, $userImage) {
        if ($this->isUserExist($username)) {
            return 0;
        } else {
            $password = md5($pass);
            $json_obj = json_decode($userImage);
            $blob = base64_decode($json_obj->blob);
            $stmt = $this->con->prepare("INSERT INTO `users` (`id`, `username`, `password`
                                        , `email`, `user_image`) VALUES (NULL, ?, ?, ?, ?);");
            $stmt->bind_param("sssb", $username, $password, $email, $blob);
            if ($stmt->execute()) {
                return 1;
            } else {
                return 2;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Send your image as byte[] arrary format to your api. And save it as byte[] array in you mySQL database.

Comment: how to send it with StringRequest of Volley

Comment: Send it this way then in your api convert that into byte[] array again.




params.put("userImage", new String(imageBytes));

Comment: no luck, wha will be the datatype for column in mysql, mine is blob